# My UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter Custom attemp method run twice

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

this is my custom filter .i have custom UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter but when open in debug mod, the attemp method being invoked twice cause the request.getInputStream() have closed the stream,
how to fix that

```
@Component
public class AuthenticateFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    public AuthenticateFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        super();
        this.setFilterProcessesUrl("/login");
        this.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        try {
            Users user = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(), Users.class);
            return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), null)
            );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
        Date now = new Date();
        String token = Jwts.builder().setIssuedAt(now)
                .setExpiration(new Date(now.getTime() + 86000000L))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, "sangdeptrai")
                .claim("username", authResult.getPrincipal().toString())
                .claim("authorities", authResult.getAuthorities())
                .compact();
        response.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void unsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException e) throws IOException, ServletException {
        ExceptionInfo exceptionInfo = new ExceptionInfo(new Date()
                ,e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value());
        response.setStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value());
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.getWriter().println(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(exceptionInfo));

    }
}
```

this id my Config file

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Config {


    private AuthenticateFilter authenticateFilter;
    private HandleExceptionFilter exceptionFilter;

    private ValidJWTFilter validJWTFilter;
    @Autowired
    public Config(AuthenticateFilter filter1, HandleExceptionFilter filter2, ValidJWTFilter filter3) {
        authenticateFilter = filter1;
        exceptionFilter = filter2;
        validJWTFilter = filter3;

    }
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(
                        req -> {
                            req.requestMatchers("/login").permitAll();
                            req.anyRequest().hasAuthority("ADMIN");
                        }
                )
                .sessionManagement((session) -> session
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                )
                .formLogin(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .addFilterAfter(exceptionFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .addFilterAfter(validJWTFilter, HandleExceptionFilter.class)
               .addFilterAfter(authenticateFilter, ValidJWTFilter.class);



        return http.build();
    }


}
```

when i enter an unvalid username, the handle eception work well, but when the authenticate pass, the attempmethod being call again,

Comment: why do you have a custom filter? handing out JWT tokens to browsers is dangerous and thats why there is no such implementation in spring security, so please explain why you are trying to build an unsecure authentication method?